# Method is not working

Tags: java, android, methods

I have the method `changeSP`, but when i call it with `changeSP("stats");`, it says:

`Return type for the method is missing`

here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class HistoryStats extends Activity{

    changeSP("stats");

    public void changeSP (String string1){
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("savedStats", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("savedStats", string1);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `changeSP("stats");` You can't have a method call like that in your class body.

Comment: Are you calling your method from onCreate()?

Comment: Put `changeSP("stats");` in a method, maybe in `onCreate(Bundle)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `changeSP("stats");` line really outside any method?

At minimum, you'll want to have an onCreate() method. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

changeSP("stats");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Call your `changeSP()` method inside `onCreate()` callback.